# Clean way to listen to asynchronous messages

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am currently writing an Engine that runs on a background thread which produces outputs asynchronously. Those outputs are gathered by a `Pipe`, whith a `readabilityHandler` that sends back the messages the main thread using `DispatchQueue.main.async` like so:

```
    private init() {
        myPipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { [weak self] handle in
            let data = handle.availableData
            if let chunk = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8), chunk.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) != "" {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.processOutput(chunk: chunk)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

On the processOutput method, I gather those message**s** (that can sometimes arrive as a block separated by newLine characters), I parse them, and I perform an action when a specific message is obtained. Ex:

```
Manager.shared.send("my command")

output: 
> info calculating...
> info calculating...
> info calculating...
> info calculating...
> result 42 // -> triggers an action 
> info calculating...
> info calculating...
```

To achieve this I rely on """listeners""" like so:

```
    private var listeners: [(token: String, handler: (String) -> ())] = []

    private func processOutput(chunk: String) {
        let split = chunk.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
        let messages = split.map({ String($0) }).filter({ $0 != "" })
        
        messages.forEach{ message in
            NSLog(" \(message)")
            
            // 1. for each message, I get the listeners, if any 
            self.listeners.filter({ message.starts(with: $0.token)  }).forEach { listener in
                // 2. they perform their action (main thread)
                listener.handler(message)
            }
            // 3. I discard the listener when done 
            self.listeners.removeAll(where: { message.starts(with: $0.token)  })
        }
    }
```

Therefore, when I need to get a message from a command I write:

```
Manager.shared.listeners.append( (token: "result", handler: { print($0) }) )
Manager.shared.send("my command")

// or 

Manager.shared.send("my command", awaits:"result") { print($0) }
```

It actually works pretty fine for now, but I have the strange feeling that this listener method is way to convoluted. I don't like the fact that I'm keeping track of all the listeners in an array, then remove it manually from it when done, I reckon it should be releasing itself. Plus in the future, I want to be able to have listeners that perform their task for a given amount of time (e.g. get options) or until the end of a timer (e.g. error handling when the response never comes).

Isn't there a cleaner way to achieve this? Is there a pattern I can read about that covers this very specific subject?

---

*Sidenote: The Engine is actually a 3rd party library game engine that I cannot modify. I cannot pass those messages directly into my methods, I have to rely on sending commands, reading the output via a pipe, but this part works actually pretty well. Its only the listenir part that I'm affraid of doing wrong. Thank you a lot*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations:

1. You should be careful with `readabilityHandler`. Your code presumes that a chunk coming will represent a full line of output. But you risk having it capture fractional portions of one or more lines. You shouldn’t make any assumptions in this regard. It may be working right now, but it is brittle, subject to significant behavior change resulting from innocuous and undocumented changes in the process you are piping.

   I might advise reading the `Data` into a buffer until you reach an end of line. A “read line” sort of pattern. You could buffer this yourself, but you can also use `lines`, an `AsyncSequence` provided by Swift concurrency, `fileHandleForReading.bytes.lines`. The you can use `for try await line in lines { … }` pattern. See `ProcessWithLines` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72122123/1271826).
2. Regarding your “listeners” structure:

   - I agree that this “closure lookup” sort of pattern feels over-engineered. This sort of approach is generally used if you are writing some general-purpose third-party API and app developers are going to be passing tokens/strings and closures to some SDK. But if you are integrating with some well-established 3rd party engine, this feels like overkill.
   - Also, assuming for a second that you really wanted this “closure lookup” sort of structure, a dictionary seems more promising/logical approach. It could conceivably have O(1) performance, rather than the O(n) scan through an array of tuples. Now, clearly, if it was going to be something more dynamic like regex lookups or some awk-like pattern matching, perhaps you’re stuck with this O(n) sort of pattern, but it seems like a strange overhead to introduce without some compelling need. (Again, if I understand your goals, you are trying to integrate with an established 3rd party engine, presumably not to design a general purpose API that works with any random pipe.)

   In short, we need to see more information about the nature of the commands and responses you will be getting via these pipes before we can advise you further on alternatives to this “listeners” pattern.